# Multiple AJAX reliant to each other and loops inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I need to make an AJAX call and return its data. When it succeeds, it should loop through each of its data and run another AJAX function for every iteration.

The problem is some lines are skipped asynchronously and so it sends a different data to the next AJAX reliant to it. I've added a comment in the code on where it goes wrong.

```
var total_sections_num;

var question_arr;

var section_arr;

function populateCreateSurvey(){

    $.ajax({

        type: 'get',

        url: "{{ url('importsurvey') }}",

        data: { survey_id: selected_survey },

        success:function(data){

            question_arr = [[],[]];

            section_arr= [];

            $(data).each(function(item, value){

                $('#survey_title').val(value.name);

                var selected_survey_id = value.survey_id;

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'get',

                    url: "{{ url('importsections') }}",

                    data: { survey_id: selected_survey_id },

                    success:function(data){

                        total_sections_num = 0;

                        $(data).each(function(item,value){

                            section_arr[total_sections_num++] = value.title;

                            var section_id = value.section_id;

                            $.ajax({

                                type: 'get',

                                url: "{{ url('importquestions') }}",

                                data: { section_id: section_id },

                                success:function(data){

                                    if (!(data.length ===0)){

                                        var i = 0;

                                        question_arr[total_sections_num] = [];

                                        $(data).each(function(item,value){

    //here is where it doesn't work as how it's supposed to. Once it gets here, total_sections_num's value is already 2 when it's supposed to be 1 first.   

                                        question_arr[total_sections_num][i++] = value.content;

                                        });

                                    }

                                }

                            }); 

                        });

                    }

                });

            });

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: google about using Promise .

Comment: this is entirely because ajax is async and you can't control the order in which the various "success" callbacks will run. Instead of looping, use a pattern where you keep an indepedendent counter of where you're up to in your `data` array, kick off the call based on the first item in the array, then when it completes, increment your counter and make the next call. Obviously you'll want to wrap up the call in a function which accepts a data item as an input parameter, otherwise you won't be able to deal with uncertain quantities of data. This is the only way to control the order it runs.

Comment: the shorthand is to use `async: false` in your ajax but this should be not implemented. The right way is depends on your workflow. so you need to tell us more information